# What Are The Potential Problems With Setting Higher Memory Limit?

Tags: php, configuration, apache2

What are the potential problems that could be encountered when the memory limit in php.ini is set to say 100MB?

Comment: You mean, besides your computer running out of memory (although that doesn't happen often nowadays)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see only the obvious one: That a greedy or broken script can hog a lot of your resources. If such a script gets requested by multiple clients simultaneously, it could become a serious resource problem for your server.

Depending on your use case, maybe it's wise to increase the memory limit on a per-script basis instead.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, if the server runs out of memory, it starts swapping (using slow hard disk for virtual memory).

If it runs out of swap, it starts killing processes at semi-random (the algorithms are complex and usually hard to predict).